# Google maps SDK Version Issue - IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am using Google maps SDK in my app and I had to support 5.0 also but Google maps does n't support 5.0. How to implement my app for 5.0

Is there any link to download Google Maps SDK 1.4.x?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's a "Releases" webpage for the GoogleMaps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases) which list what's changed from version to version.

They do allow downloading releases from one or two versions back, but there's no actual link there for 1.4.X.

However, [when I tried manually typing in a link of "https://dl.google.com/geosdk/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.4.3.zip"](https://dl.google.com/geosdk/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.4.3.zip), it successfully downloaded.  Grab it now, because it is likely to be gone within the next month or two.

Comment: The "Releases" web page says that the 1.5 version of GoogleMaps SDK got rid of iOS 5.1 support, so a download of the 1.4.3 SDK *should* be working.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried with 1.5, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3... with IOS 5.1 But am not able to run my application. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru I have a "live" app with 1.4.3 SDK with support for IOS 5.1; maybe there is somethings else... depend of your errors..